# Query cassandra table in Databricks using python cassandra driver

Tags: python, pyspark, cassandra, databricks

I'm trying to optimize a way to query a cassadnra table when working in databricks. After reading this article https://medium.com/@yoke_techworks/cassandra-and-pyspark-5d7830512f19, the author suggest to query the cassandra table one row at the time and union each results.

My attempt, using the python cassandra driver, is this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import pandas as pd

def init_cassandra_session(endpoints, keyspace, username, password, port=9042):
    
    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username, password)
    cluster = Cluster(endpoints, port=port, auth_provider=auth_provider)
    cassandra_session = cluster.connect(keyspace, wait_for_all_pools=False)
    return cassandra_session

def get_rdd_values(rows):
    out_df = None
    cassandra_session = init_cassandra_session(host, keyspace, username, password)
    for row in rows:
        device_id = row.__getitem__('device_id')
        timestamp = row.__getitem__('timestamp')
        category = row.__getitem__('category')
        query = '''
                select * from headcounter_category_h_aggr where device_id = '%s' and timestamp = '&s' and category = '%s'
                '''
        result_query = cassandra_session.execute(query, [device_id, timestamp, category])
        if out_df is None:
            out_df = result_query
        else:
            out_df = out_df.append(result_query)
    
    return out_df 

columns = ['device_id', 'timestamp', 'category']
data = [['SIMUL_TEST03', '2020-12-23 11:00:00', 'PERSON'], ['SIMUL_TEST03', '2020-12-23 12:00:00', 'PERSON']]

pdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
dfFromData1 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

rdd_values = dfFromData1.rdd.mapPartitions(get_rdd_values)
rdd_values.collect()
```

when try to collect the results, rdd_values seams to be NoneType and so it's not iterable.

I cannot find the error I'm making.

EDIT

I resolved the issue: I changed the *get_rdd_values()* function like this:

```
def get_rdd_values(rows):
    out_df = []
    cassandra_session = init_cassandra_session(host, keyspace, username, password)
    for row in rows:
        device_id = row.__getitem__('device_id')
        timestamp = row.__getitem__('timestamp')
        category = row.__getitem__('category')
        query = f"select * from headcounter_category_h_aggr where device_id = '{device_id}' and timestamp = '{timestamp}' and category = '{category}'"
        result_query = cassandra_session.execute(query)
        if len(out_df)== 0:
            out_df = result_query
        else:
            out_df = out_df.append(result_query)
    
    return out_df
```

But now it seams to make two time the same query or at least the out_df is made from two identical element

EDIT 2 and **solution**:

After some attempts I found out that making a spark dataframe directly from the RDD removes duplicate row. Here the code:

`dfFromRDD = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_values, schema = schema)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this - instead you need to use [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) that provides native access to Cassandra from Spark using DataFrame APIs ([documentation for PySpark](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md)).  You just need to install a [version matching your Databricks Runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly) (on Databricks you need to use `assembly` version due the reasons described [here](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/working-with-datastax-astra-from.html)), and then you'll be able to query Cassandra very easily, like this:

```py
df = spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="table_name", keyspace="ks_name")\
    .load()
```

or integrate with Spark catalogs like this:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.myCatalog", 
   "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
df = spark.read.table("myCatalog.myKs.myTab")
```

And Spark Cassandra Connector will perform predicates pushdown where it's possible (for example, when you query by partition key).

If you need to join your dataset with Cassandra table, then you can follow instructions on use of so-called direct join outlined in the following [blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html).

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for the fast reply. Whato you describe was my previus approach, but given what is written in the article i linked I tought that passing trought mapPartition was a better solution to not load the entire cassadnra table in databricks. I forgot to tell that I started working with databricks not so long ago.

Comment: it's really depends on your use case. In many cases connector will try to read as little data as possible by applying provided filters. You can always do `.explain()` on the dataframe and see where filtering happens - in the Cassandra or Spark.

Comment: My concern is the "IN" clause while querying the cassandra table. Using .explain()  confirmed that IN is used in the cassandra part of the filter leading to performance issue. It works for now, but in the future, or in another project, this could be a problem.

Comment: The best way to do this is to convert `IN` into a DirectJoin. You can do it explicitly, or you can rely on connector (see section "Parallelization of IN clauses in Spark SQL" in this blog post: https://www.datastax.com/blog/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)